# How To Generate POJOs From SQL Server DB?

Tags: eclipse, ssms

I am using Eclipse 2018 with SQL Server management studio 2017, but I can not find a way in both of them, to generate entities from the SQL Server database.

Now I have to manually create them one by one with the following syntax:

```
@Entity(name="client")
public class Client implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
..
}
```

Is there a better approach to save time?

**UPDATE**

Thank you @Aniruddhsinh, I created an empty JPA project then a connection using a special driver with jdbc.jar [here](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54671) -(sql server options proposed did not work), and I provided the url, db, username, password, then using JPA tools, now I can copy those classes in my spring-boot project.

Comment: Using Visual Studio with Entity Framework's database-first can save you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create pojo classes from dB in eclipse follow this example https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm. From there using JPA first connect database and on selection of table generate classes.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, I created an empty JPA project then a connection using a `special` driver with jdbc.jar https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54671 -(sql server options proposed did not work), and I provided url, db, username, password, then using JPA tools and that connection, it works, now I can copy those classe in my spring-boot project.